# numba np.diff with axis=0

Tags: python, numpy, numba

While using numba, `axis=0` is acceptable parameters for `np.sum()`, but not with `np.diff()`. Why is this happening? I'm working with 2D, thus axis specification is needed.

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def jitsum(y):
    np.sum(y, axis=0)

@jit(nopython=True)
def jitdiff(y): #this one will cause error
    np.diff(y, axis=0)
```

Error: `np_diff_impl() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

A workaround in 2D will be:

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def jitdiff(y):
    np.diff(y.T).T
```

Comment: It looks like the handling of `axis` is not implemented in the numba version of `diff`: https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/61ec1fd0f69aeadece218dccf4c39ebc5c7dfbc4/numba/np/arraymath.py#L3590-L3626

Comment: Thanks, that's the true answer on *why*.  Should add issue/PR to make it support `axis` [there](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.diff` on a 2D array with `n=1`, `axis=1` is just

```
a[:, 1:] - a[:, :-1]
```

For `axis=0`:

```
a[1:, :] - a[:-1, :]
```

I suspect that the lines above will compile just fine with numba.

Comment: Thank you, and indeed that was faster that `np.diff` and two times transpose approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum(y):
    a=np.sum(y, axis=0)
    b=np.sum(y,axis=1)
    print("Sum along the rows (axis=0):",a)
    print("Sum along the columns (axis=1):",b)

def diff_order1(y):
    a=np.diff(y,axis=0,n=1)
    b=np.diff(y,axis=1,n=1) ## n=1 indicates 1st order difference 
    print("1st order difference along the rows (axis=0):",a)
    print("1st order difference along the columns (axis=1):",b)

def diff_order2(y):
    a=np.diff(y,axis=0,n=2)
    b=np.diff(y,axis=1,n=2) ## n=2 indicates 2nd order difference 
    print("2nd order difference along the rows (axis=0):",a)
    print("2nd order difference along the columns (axis=1):",b)
```

This function is just another version of solving the problem calling the .diff function twice for order 2 difference

```
def diff_order2_v2(y):
  a=np.diff(np.diff(y,axis=1),axis=1)
  b=np.diff(np.diff(y,axis=0),axis=0)
  print("2nd order difference along the rows (axis=0):",a)
  print("2nd order difference along the columns (axis=1):",b)
```

Try running this code, I tried to create functions for sum function and difference function for 1st order and 2nd order difference.

Comment: This answer will not work on `numba`. See @Warren comment.